# How to use Modifier.transformable and Modifier.pointerInput together in Jepack Compose

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-gesture

I want to build an Image Cropper myself. Because I need to zoom into the image and also detect drags on the borders/corners of the Cropping Window, I need to use `Modifier.transformable()` and `Modifier.pointerInput(detectDragGestures {})` together.

But one of them always blocks the other one.

Is there a way to use those two Modifier together? Or do I build my own `Modifier.transformable` to get it to work?